# Confused about the behavior of mouseenter/leave and hover in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover, mouseenter

I was looking over the jQuery documentation and found that, when I try to pass two function into ***hover()*** , the first one behaves similar to ***mouseenter()*** and second one behaves similar to ***mouseleave()***. Take a look at the following code snippet.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1);
        },
        function(){
            $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.25);
        }
    );
});
```

is similar as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1);
    });
    $('div').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.25);
    });
});
```

Actually what's the difference between these two ?

Comment: There is no difference between the two examples you have, although you could chain the events off the same selector to improve performance. Could you explain what you mean in your second question.

Comment: I think I should study more before asking the second question. Thank you.

Comment: hi may this post help ur question ...http://www.quora.com/jQuery/What-is-the-difference-between-the-hover-and-mouseover-functions